# Rename tag [motionjoy] to [motioninjoy]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-rename-request

The tag [motionjoy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motionjoy) refers to the tool that allows you to use a PS3 controller on a PC. However the tool is actually called *MotionInJoy* (note that is *Motion-**In**-joy*), as per their [website](http://www.motioninjoy.com/).

Can we rename the tag to use the correct spelling?

**Note:** It's also known by it's other name: *DS3Tool*, which could be a synonym, (or the entire tag could change to [motioninjoy-ds3tool](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motioninjoy-ds3tool)) but I digress from the main issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's four questions. You have more than 2k rep. Just edit them.

Not every situation like this needs a big meta discussion. **If you See Something, Do Something.**