# Rename [ace-combat-ah] -> [ace-combat-assault-horizon]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to suggest renaming the two tags relating to *Ace Combat: Assault Horizon*

- [ace-combat-ah](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ace-combat-ah) -> [ace-combat-assault-horizon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ace-combat-assault-horizon)
- [ace-combat-ahl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ace-combat-ahl) -> [ace-combat-assault-horizon-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ace-combat-assault-horizon-legacy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done, *however*

- This change affected 3 questions total.
- There were no tag wikis or excerpts that would be saved by a tag merge
- Keeping the old tags as synonyms in this case would be benign at best (and I have removed them).

For smaller tags like this we probably don't need a whole meta about it. You have the reputation to [create tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) and to [edit without needing review/approval](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Next time just go ahead and change the tags yourself.

Comment: I will keep this in mind in the future. Thank you for the change.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro No prob. I [learned this lesson myself](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7593/28182).